# AWS Kinesis firehose : how to change the timestamp from UTC to Singapore?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, timezone, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have created a firehose kinesis stream to put our data in S3 in !{timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd} format.

Is there any way to change the Timezone for this from UTC to Singapore timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the names of the objects that Firehose creates in Amazon S3.

If you wish, you could create an AWS Lambda function that *moves* the objects to a new name. See an example in: [Rename an incoming S3 file with a random directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62926253/174777)