# Rename an incoming S3 file with a random directory structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this  app that will send a file to a s3 bucket. unfortunately I cannot change the path it sends it to in s3 so I have to figure out a way to get this file.

mys3bucket: /apps/region/020-07-14T22:24:34Z/details.csv

As you can see the date, the app places the date into the path. I am trying to not hard code items to make it more flexible.

what I want to do is get that details.csv file rename and move it to another location within the same s3 bucket. basically its permanent location.

what I was trying was something like this but it clearly will not work with the random path. the only piece that I can make a variable for is:

path = /apps/region/   the next level is random, but the report name is always the same.

clearly im not trying this the correct way but as of now I am not sure.

```
s3.Object( 'mys3bucket' ,'account3_details.csv').copy_from(CopySource='mys3bucket/apps/region/2020-07-14T22:24:34Z/details.csv')
s3.Object( 'mys3bucket','/apps/region/2020-07-14T22:24:34Z/details.csv').delete()
```

Comment: Why don't you add an s3 event trigger lambda function?

Comment: mainly because i know nothing about lambda at this moment. does sound interesting though

Comment: Go and give it a shot! For your use case, it's definitely the right way to do it. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) is the tutorial, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is quite simple to accomplish in Lambda. How should it determine the "permanent" filename? Is it just incrementing from some previous name (`details001.csv`), or would it be based on the timestamp from the source file (`details-2020-07-14`), or perhaps the timestamp when the file was actually uploaded (which might be different)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - to answer your question. In the end I was thinking of sending it to a different folder path like: /apps/region/out/details001.csv (increment it). the script that creates the details.csv will be ran weekly to bi-weekly. saving them to the alternate location was my thought....... I wish I had your guys vote of confidence on being easy :)  but you guys know best....I try to do thing outside the console even if means struggling a bit. this sounds like a 100% console thing if I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code from a function I previously wrote. When triggered by an Amazon S3 Event, it moves the object to a new location:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
TARGET_PATH = 'foo/'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Extract filename without path
    filename = ('/' + source_key).rsplit('/', 1)[1]

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(TARGET_PATH + filename).copy(copy_source)
    s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(source_key).delete()
```

You would need to modify the logic that determines the destination filename (Key) of the copied object.

Comment: thank you so much...  i will use as a base and play with it.  So this is one piece of the puzzle. I can really under this piece. Where I am not struggling is where to go from here once I get the lambda handler created.  was going over the doc which 'jellycsc' posted about a tutorial. I was going through it. I got to step 5. but I do not understand what comes next. it just stops on the page. I get if I already created my function and substituted it for the example lambda_function.py..but I just do not know what comes next.

Comment: First, create an AWS Lambda function with the above code. Give it an IAM Role that has the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy and also permission to call `CopyObject` and `DeleteObject` on the desired S3 buckets (at a minimum). Then, at the top of the Lambda page, click "+ Trigger" and add an S3 trigger for _'All object create events'_. Select the source bucket and provide a prefix (if you want it only to trigger on files added in a particular location). Then, test it by uploading a file to S3. You can debug by going to the Lambda 'Monitoring' tab and clicking "View logs in CloudWatch".

Comment: ok thank you now it is clearer. One last pestering question.. all this info is great.... later on if I wanted to, could I add to this to function to maybe have it email the report or some other magical item in addition to what it currently does?

Comment: You can code a Lambda function to do whatever you wish.

Comment: So it works nice. thank you all for the push. So the file that initially makes it to the s3 bucket before it gets move. That is done by an api call itself, but manually.  with the current setup, is it possible to have a cloudwatch trigger also initiate that initial API call like  cron than all the other magic happens.   I guess if not i can make a separate lambda for it  I just didnt know because we are using the s3 trigger

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused by what you're asking. It is possible to trigger an AWS Lambda function on a schedule from Amazon CloudWatch Events. But I don't know what else you are asking there. If you wish, you can create a new question and provide more details.