# s3 lambda - move only file place in a particular folder

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, boto3

So I got some great help on creating a s3 lambda. works great

which can be referenced here:
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925258/rename-an-incoming-s3-file-with-a-random-directory-structure/62926253?noredirect=1#comment111283588_62926253)

my issue, once this lambda script does its thing and places the file in its final resting place. the file will be manipulated, possibly renamed. this would trigger the lambda func again.  This is why i am wondering how to restrict the lambda func to look in a particular  location.

my issue seems to be that any file sent to s3 will get triggered by the lambda func.

To make it more complicated.  the api that originally sends the file to the s3 bucket creates that path with a timestamp in it like (which I can't change)

```
/apps/region/2020-07-14T22:24:34Z/details.csv
```

is there any way to limit the cool lamda func to only look at this particular path and be able to find the details.csv file. Maybe just the first part of the path?

Here is the code: (from other request for help)

Note: i have changed just some of the things pertinent to my specific env per John's notation

```
import boto3
import urllib

TARGET_BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
TARGET_PATH = 'foo/'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Get incoming bucket and key
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    source_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    # Extract filename without path
    filename = ('/' + source_key).rsplit('/', 1)[1]

    # Copy object to different bucket
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket,
        'Key': source_key
    }
    s3_resource.Bucket(TARGET_BUCKET).Object(TARGET_PATH + filename).copy(copy_source)
    s3_resource.Bucket(source_bucket).Object(source_key).delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the notification to use [object key name filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering).

Check out [this user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html#enable-event-notifications-how-to) of how to enable and configure event notifications for an S3 Bucket.

> 8. To filter event notifications by a prefix or suffix, enter a Prefix or a Suffix.
>
> For example, you can set up a prefix filter so that you receive notifications only when files are added to a specific folder (for example, images/).